# The power output of an amplifier is 6W. The power gain is 80. What is the input power?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The power output of an amplifier is 6W. The power gain is 80. What is the input power?

so we know that 
$$A_p=80$$
$$V\text{ out}= 6 \text W$$
$$V\text{ input} =?$$
Power Gain is $80$

[image]

$$\text{ input}=\ldots.$$

help me out

Comment: $ gain = \frac{output power}{input power}$

Comment: 80=(6W/INPUT POWER)

Comment: So do I multiply 80V x 6W?

Comment: Divide 6w by 80. 80 should be a ratio not volts.

Answer (score 0):

Since the power gain is a ratio of $\frac{W}{W}$, then we use
$$ \mbox{Gain}=\frac{P_{out}}{P_{in}} $$
Thus
$$ 80=\frac{6W}{P_{in}}$$
$$ P_{in}=\frac{6W}{80} = 0.075W $$

Comment: You are supposing the gain is $80$ dB, not a multiplier of $80$.  I don't think that is clear in the question.

Comment: @RossMillikan, I agree. Please see my edit.